# Access SQL: sum Sales of one Product for 2016 and 2017 in one sql-query

Tags: sql, ms-access

i want to get for each product the Sum of sales in year 2016 and year 2017.

i tried:

```
Select
productid,
Switch(year(DATE)=2016,sum(salesa1)) as sales16,
Switch(year(DATE)=2017,sum(salesa1)) as sales17
From Sales
Group by productid
```

probably i have something wrong, could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The condition needs to go *inside* the `sum()`:

```
Select productid,
       sum(switch(year(DATE) = 2016, salesa1)) as sales16,
       sum(switch(year(DATE) = 2017, salesa1)) as sales17
From Sales
Group by productid
```